# Evaluating slow website

Tags: mysql, apache2, performance-testing, database-performance

I'm trying to trouble shoot a website that my company hosts that seems to run very poorly during peak times. The site was developed by a developer (who has left the company) and was built on Zend-Framework and is currently hosted on a single EC2 instance on AWS. Both the database and apache are hosted on the same machine.

So where do I start when trying to trouble shoot the poor performance. Are there certain metrics that I should keep my eye out for that will be useful in telling me where the problems might be.

When looking on the server and running Top I do see the MySQL database start to spike and at time take of 70% or my of the CPU, but then starts to return back to normal after a few seconds. In terms of Apache what trouble spots should I be looking for there?

Okay, I know this vague, but any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Floyd

Comment: This might smell like poor MySQL requests, perhaps because some MySQL tables are missing appropriate indexes.

Comment: I wish it where that simple. But all the tables are pretty well indexed.

Comment: There's a difference between "pretty well indexed" and "appropriately indexed". No amount of indexes will help if the query you're running does not use them. Can you turn on the slow query low (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) or log query execution times? I'd bet on slow queries, too.

Comment: I can try turing on the slow query log to see what that tells me. I'm also wondering if I need to change the query_cache or increase the amount of threads that are avialable. Do these settings help alot?